# Get Events for Day in Another Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to search for an event in a different calendar other than the default calendar. No matter what I try, I keep getting a ".getEventsForDay is not a function" error.

I've tried:

```
let calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('MyCalendarName');
let myEvent = calendars.getEventsForDay(new Date(2023, 3, 3), {search: 'Event Title'});
```

and

```
let myEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('MyCalendarName').getEventsForDay(new Date(2023, 3, 3), {search: 'Event Title'});
```

And both return an error. I'm not sure why?
Is there another way to pull an event from a non-default calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in your script returns an array, so you need to specify which item in your next line. It should look like this:

```
let myEvent = calendars[0].getEventsForDay(new Date(2023, 3, 3), {search: 'Event Title'});
```

```
let myEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('MyCalendarName')[0].getEventsForDay(new Date(2023, 3, 3), {search: 'Event Title'});
```